# magento 2 setup:install error

Tags: magento2, php, extensions, installation

all. I'm using MacOS High Sierra.
I have so many problems with installing magento 2. For example: now I need use command :

```
bin/magento setup:install --admin-firstname=pavel --admin-lastname=konchych --admin-email=admin@example.com  --admin-user=pavelkonchych --admin-password=xdemonx1234  --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=root
```

But how you can understand - where I have an error :

```
    Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 513]
Required extensions check...


  [Exception]                                    
  Missing following extensions: 'mcrypt' 'intl'
```

If you want to sad about extensions in **php.ini** - I can say, that is not a problem because I have all need extensions without `;`

```
    ; Extensions

MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apcu.so
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apc.so
extension=imap.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=intl.so

MAMP_Imagick_MAMPextension=imagick.so
MAMP_Tidy_MAMPextension=tidy.so
MAMP_Oauth_MAMPextension=oauth.so
MAMP_Igbinary_MAMPextension=igbinary.so
MAMP_Memcached_MAMPextension=memcached.so
MAMP_Redis_MAMPextension=redis.so
;extension=uploadprogress.so
;extension=yaml.so
```

And at the end of a question, I want to add screenshot where we have something strange - if I'm trying to check these PHP extensions in wizard install - we don't have any errors

[image]

I want to know, how I can disabling this checking or what I must doing?!?

In php_error.log :

```
[27-Oct-2018 07:52:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[27-Oct-2018 07:52:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[27-Oct-2018 07:52:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
[27-Oct-2018 07:52:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4384

Comment: @BartZalas nvm - I'm just installed in browser...

Comment: @BartZalas but my MacBook Air late 2010 - can't load page :D 5 minute loading

Comment: is it stack on installation ?

Comment: @BartZalas no, all was good, I don’t know why I can’t install by terminal but I can easy install by browser. But I see how many resources needed for Magento 2. Thanks a lot of helping.

Answer (score -1):

check if those modules are enable for `cli` also

Comment: How I can do this?

Comment: php -i | grep mcrypt run this command from terminal and see if display mcrypt module or not

Comment: Yes, he is. I see mcrypt

Comment: sudo phpenmod mcrypt run this command and restart apache and check

Comment: Okay, I’m trying

Comment: `sudo: phpenmod: command not found`

Comment: which os you are using? and which php version is display in cli mode? because phpenmod work fine in ubuntu 16.04 with php7.1

Comment: MacOS high Sierra, and php version 7.0.31

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329999/mcrypt-php-extension-required-on-mac-os-x try this

Comment: That is not helped me(